# Parse page using AngleSharp

Tags: c#, .net, anglesharp

I want to parse website using c# with AngleSharp, it's easy to do with static pages, but there is a problem, I can't parse info avalible only for authorized users. What should I do to autorize programmatically into website and parse all info avalible for me?

Comment: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/242

Comment: did you try accessing the web site with `HttpClient`, adding the proper http headers in order to pass validation, and only then use angleSharp to parse the page returned after successful validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the used authorization scheme this may either be super simple or ultra hard / impossible.

So let's first visit what can be done with AngleSharp:

- Any kind of requests incl. their manipulation (on request, but also before response)
- General cookie management (and their manipulation, of course)
- Querying the DOM and perform "simple" actions (e.g., clicking a button, submitting a form)
- Running trivial JavaScript files

Here trivial means: Scripts that do not need any capabilities beyond what AngleSharp offers, e.g., rendering tree information, advanced CSSOM access, ... - or scripts that require non-ES5 compliant parsers (e.g., make use of ES6 or some special non-standard capabilities).

Now since I do not know what is the authorization scheme or exact problem that you are hitting (some code / MWE would be helpful!) I'll just go for a simple click example.

```
var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies());
var loginPage = await context.OpenAsync("http://yourpage.com");
var loginForm = loginPage.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>("form");
var profilePage = await loginForm.SubmitAsync(new { userName = "myUser", password = "password" });
// get something on profilePage
```

Note that in this example the form field names for the login form are `userName` and `password` - they may be different for your login page. Also note that your page may contain multiple forms and the selector could be more sophisticated than a simple `form`.

HTH!